# Disabling browser scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi 
Is it possible to disable browser scroll bar through java script...? If yes how?

Help me if anybody knows it... 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

CSS

```
body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

javascript

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

jQuery

```
$("body").css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

Comment: This is not disabling, it simply hides it.

Answer (score 9):

Use this CSS

```
body {
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ya sure you can disable browser scroll bar
just give overflow hidden for body tag using css and javascript

or just put an id for the body tag and use

eg 
HTML

```
<body id="page">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 document.getElementById( "page" ).style.overflow= "hidden";
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following snippet;

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are other possible values for overflow

```
overflow = document.body.style.overflow

/* Keyword values */
overflow: "visible";
overflow: "hidden";
overflow: "clip";
overflow: "scroll";
overflow: "auto";
overflow: "hidden visible";

/* Global values */
overflow: "inherit";
overflow: "initial";
overflow: "revert";
overflow: "unset";
```